# Association for type declaration statements in C

Tags: c

How are type declaration statements in C parsed (Right to Left or Left to Right)?

eg: consider the statement:

```
const char* const arr="hello";
```

How exactly is the above statement parsed?

Dear All, To those who found it difficult to understand my question:

In the above declaration statement arr is a variable. When the above statement is read by the compiler (which happens to parse the line) is arr considered a constant variable and then categorised as a character pointer or is it first recognised as a character pointer and then concluded with a constant value. 
The doubt is due to the following thought:
    If only const were to be declared ex: const int x; then the compiler does things behind the scene to make it a constant, and If I were to declare only a pointer ex: int* x; again compiler does things behind the scenes to categorise x as a pointer variable to distinguish it from just another integer variable. But in case the declaration is something like:
const int* const x; the behind the scenes action has to happen in some order so as x is recognised as and integer pointer variable and a const variable and then that has a constant value. 
  I would also be glad to hear the "behind the scenes" actions that C compiler does to separate between int variable char vaiable... pointer variable, register variable, In all how does a compiler recognise the difference.
   Finally thanks for your patience to read such a long question.

Comment: C isn't a parsing language, it is a compiled execution language.

Comment: what do you mean by _parsed_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I'd guess he wants to know which character of the literal getas asigned first or "notified" But thats not the way C works. (anyway we only can assume what he means)

Comment: ahhhh, or its about the const part

Comment: @Zaibis: I believe OP wants to know how to parse the type in their head.

Comment: @Zaibis yeah, basically it's `unclear what you're asking`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/301207

Answer (score 1):

Declarations aren't parsed strictly left to right or right to left.  C declaration syntax is somewhat complicated.

Based on the grammar found in the [online C2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.7, your example parses out like so (skipping a few steps for brevity):

```
  char    const      *    const      arr      =    "hello"        ;
  -+--    --+--      ^    --+--      -+-      ^    ---+---        ^
   |        |        |      |         |       |       |           |
  type     type      |    type      direct    |   initializer     |
specifier qualifier  | qualifier  declarator  |       |           |
   |        |        |    list        |       |       |           |
   |        |        |      |         |       |       |           |
   |        |        +--+---+         |       |       |           |
   |        |           |             |       |       |           |
   |        |         pointer         |       |       |           |
   |        |           |             |       |       |           |
   |        |           +------+------+       |       |           |
   |        |                  |              |       |           |
   |        |              declarator         |       |           |
   |        |                  |              |       |           |
   |        |                  +---------+----+-------+           |
   |        |                            |                        |
   |        |                            |                        |
   |        |                            |                        |
   +---+----+                            |                        |
       |                                 |                        |
   declaration                  init-declarator-list              |
   specifiers                            |                        |
       |                                 |                        |
       +-------------------------+-------+------------------------+
                                 |
                            declaration
```

So, something to note about the pointer part of the declaration; the `const` following the `*` is part of the *`pointer`* non-terminal.  That part of the grammar looks like this:

```
pointer:
    * type-qualifier-listopt
    * type-qualifier-listopt pointer
```

When you write `T * const p`, that means you are declaring `p` as a *constant pointer*; you will not be able to assign a different value to `p` (you can't make it point to a different object).

This also means you can declare an object like `T * const * const p`, or `T * const restrict * volatile * p;`. In each case, the list of type qualifiers is associated with the `*` appearing to their left.

The way to read hairy declarations is to start with the left-most identifier and work your way out, remembering the following rules:

```
*a[]      - a is an array of pointer
(*a)[]    - a is a pointer to an array
*f()      - f is a function returning a pointer
(*f)()    - f is a pointer to a function
* qual p  - p is a qualified pointer
qual * p  - p is a pointer to qualified type
```

where *qualified* may be one of `const`, `volatile`, `restrict`, or `_Atomic`.  In the case of function declarations, you'll be applying these rules recursively to each function parameter.

So,

```
                   arr               -- arr
           * const arr               -- is a const pointer to
char const * const arr               -- const char
char const * const arr = "hello";    -- initialized to "hello"
```

This could also be written

```
const char * const arr = "hello";
```

and it will mean the same thing.  The reason for this is that the *`declaration-specifiers`* non-terminal (which, in this case, covers the part of the declaration to the left of the `*`) is defined as

```
declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
```

This syntax means you can have any one of a *`storage-class-specifier`*, a *`type-specifier`*, a *`type-qualifier`*, a *`function-specifier`*, or an *`alignment-specifier`* followed by zero or more additional such items (subject to certain constraints).  This is how you can get declarations like

```
static unsigned long int x;
```

which parses as

```
static        unsigned        long        int         x        ;
--+---        ----+---        --+-        -+-         ^        ^
  |               |             |          |          |        |
storage         type           type       type      direct     |
 class        specifier      specifier  specifier  declarator  |
specifier         |             |          |          |        |
  |               |             |       declaration   |        |
  |               |             |       specifiers    |        |
  |               |             |          |          |        |
  |               |             +-----+----+          |        |
  |               |                   |               |        |
  |               |               declaration       init       |
  |               |               specifiers      declarator   |
  |               |                   |               |        |
  |               +---------+---------+               |        |
  |                         |                         |        |
  |                     declaration                   |        |
  |                     specifiers                    |        |
  |                         |                         |        |
  +-----------+-------------+                       init       |
              |                                   declarator   |
      declaration-specifiers                        list       |
              |                                       |        |
              +----------------------+----------------+--------+
                                     |
                                declaration
```

The order in which `static`, `unsigned`, `long`, and `int` appear doesn't matter (although people will probably hit you if you write `int long static unsigned x`).  Your declaration must include at least one *`type-specifier`*, and you can't write things like `float char double x` or `double double double double y`, but those rules are enforced at a different level.

Answer (score 0):

In C, variables are declared the way you use them, e.g.

   `int * t[12];`

means than *t[somevalue]  is an int.

Back to your example :

`const char *arr = "hello";`

means you cannot change the chars inside the string

- arr[0] = 'x' is forbidden
- arr = "xyz" is allowed

`char * const arr = "hello";`

means you cannot change the value of the pointer arr

- arr[0] = 'x' is allowed
- arr = "xyz" is forbidden

Comment: sorry, typo. I mixed up with cut and paste. Edited.